# How to toggle class only current element angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

here is my code examples.
In my case toggle class works for every `li` element

```
   <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
        <li *ngFor="let x of nav" class="presentation" (click)="active = !active" [ngClass]="toggleClass()">
            <a href="#">{{x.menu}} </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

js

```
 export class AppComponent {
  active = false;
  nav = NAVIGATION;

  //Toggle Class

  toggleClass(){
    if(this.active){
      return 'active';
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With following code, you don't need to write typescript code,

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
        <li *ngFor="let x of nav;let i=index" 
             class="presentation" 
             (click)="isClicked=i"             
             [class.active]="isClicked==i">    
             <a href="#">{{x.menu}}</a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make a directive and use @HostBinding

Example

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[my-directive]'
})

export class MyDirective {
    @HostBinding('class.active') isActive = false;

    toggle() {
        this.isActive = !this.isActive;
    }

}
```

Use like this :

```
<li [my-directive] (click)="toggle()">blah</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should store the active variable per item, not on the whole component with all the li's:

```
<li *ngFor="let x of nav" (click)="x.active = !x.active" ... >
```

You can use the following code in your template to display active class:

```
[class.active]="x.active"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an `active` property to your nav interface/class:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
   <li *ngFor="let x of nav" 
       class="presentation" 
       (click)="nav.active = !nav.active" 
       [class.active]="nav.active"
   >
      <a href="#">{{x.menu}} </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

But seeing as that you are trying to select a navigation item, i would guess that you only want to select one. You have to change your template to something like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
   <li *ngFor="let x of nav" 
       class="presentation" 
       (click)="active = x" 
       [class.active]="x === active"
   >
      <a href="#">{{x.menu}} </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

In your component you should change your `active` declaration from `boolean` to your nav item class/interface/any

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HostListener for the directive to be pure

```
export class MyDirective {
@HostBinding('class.active') isActive = false;

@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
onClick(e) {
   this.isActive = !this.isActive;
}
}
```

And use the html

```
<li [my-directive]>blah</li>
```